# What is 0 and 0 in hw:0,0 mean? and how can I get those value?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ffmpeg

I'm trying to do screencast and record application sound too with ffmpeg. But, I can't get the application sound recorded. I think there's something wrong with my command. What I'm doing is like this:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0,0 -f x11grab -i :0.0 out.mpg
```

So, i need to understand what is 0 and 0 in `hw:0,0` means. When I do `arecord -l` the output is:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20585 Analog [CX20585 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and `aplay -l` output is:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20585 Analog [CX20585 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The output gives many of `0` values. I don't know which one to put in `hw:#,#` so `ffmpeg` can record the application sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `0` is the card, and the second `0` is the device, as listed in the output of `arecord -l`:

`card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20585 Analog [CX20585 Analog]`

Comment: Why it doesn't record audio output? I mean directly, not from microphone. I tried to record screen while playing mp3, but the output video doesn't play that mp3 I played while recording.

Comment: Because that audio is not being output through the input of the audio card, and you are recording from the audio input. If you want to record via loopback, you will need a loopback device configured so that audio output is also recorded on the loopback device input. Or alternatively, use a video editing application to combine the video recording and audio recording, into a single file, where you can control the timing more discreetly.